# if statement: whether an array has units/dimensions (pint)

Tags: python, if-statement, pint

My variable C0 is defined in pint.UnitRegistry units mol/L. I need to use it in a function, but in order for Python to not call me on inconsistent units for the general function, I have to define a new variable in the function with units, as follows.

```
import pint
u = pint.UnitRegistry()

C0      = [10**(-3),10**(-6),0] *u.mol/u.L

def r(c,t):
    C = c * u.mol/u.L   #Python expects c to be dimensionless
    return ν * k[3]*C0[1]*C[0] / ((k[2]+k[3])/k[1] + C[0]) #k and ν are arrays for the problem I'm working on.
```

I want to add an if statement so that I don't end up with C in r(C0,t) being in units of mol^2/L^2. What I have is

```
def r(c,t):
    if c.dimensionless == True:
        C = c * u.mol/u.L
    else:
        C = c
    return ν * k[3]*C0[1]*C[0] / ((k[2]+k[3])/k[1] + C[0])
```

But when I run this with C0, it tells me that C0 has no attribute called dimensionless. How should I edit my if statement so it will work to check any kind of input for units?

Traceback:

```
File [Redacted], line 32, in <module>
    Ct = odeint(r,C0,t)

  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 233, in odeint
    int(bool(tfirst)))

  File [Redacted], line 24, in r
    if c.dimensionless == True:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dimensionless'
```

Comment: What is `type(c)` in `r(c,t)` when you get the error?

Comment: @WilliamMiller thanks for asking. I've added the traceback information. To answer your question directly, type (c) is noted in the traceback as numpy.ndarray

Comment: You should add that code as an answer to your question if it works for you since comments aren't the proper place for large code blocks (esp for a language like python where the indentation matters so much!)

Comment: @WilliamMiller thanks. Really new to navigating this site.

Comment: No worries, we've all been new here before. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

After looking around I found that the pint.UnitRegistry.Quantity function allows for a dimensionality check on items without a native 'dimensionality' attribute. Note also the reversed order of copying and adding units from above.

```
def r(c,t):
    if u.Quantity(c).dimensionality == 'substance/length**3':
        C = c
    else:
        C = c   * u.mol/u.L
    return ν * k[3]*C0[1]*C[0] / ((k[2]+k[3])/k[1] + C[0])
```